# After wakeup computer can't ping remote device on first attempt

Tags: networking, windows-11

After upgrading PC from Windows 10 to 11, the PC after wakeup/reboot can't connect to another device on network on first attempt, but always connects on second attempt.

The PC has 2 network cards, wireless that connected to the internet via a router and wired which connected to a network switch where the network device is also connected to.
The wireless adapter is using default settings and it's IP is `192.168.1.43`, wired network adapter has set manual IP address to `192.168.1.212`, the device's IP is `192.168.1.210`

The strange part is, when I ping the device, the first attempt goes to a wrong IP address:

```
PS C:\> ping 192.168.1.210

Pinging 192.168.1.210 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.43: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.210:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms
```

With wireless adapter disabled I get this:

```
PS C:\> ping 192.168.1.210

Pinging 192.168.1.210 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.210: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.210:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

[EDIT]
After wakeup `arp -a` returns:

```
PS C:\> arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.43 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           04-a1-51-30-01-07     dynamic
  192.168.1.2           00-40-9d-67-5e-3c     dynamic
  192.168.1.19          b0-fc-36-76-e9-ad     dynamic
  192.168.1.76          00-00-00-04-fd-7f     dynamic
  192.168.1.250         9c-3d-cf-e1-d8-0c     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

but after first ping it shows this:

```
PS C:\> arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.212 --- 0xc
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.210         00-01-15-e2-97-00     dynamic
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.1.60            01-00-5e-00-01-3c     static
  224.0.6.151           01-00-5e-00-06-97     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static

Interface: 192.168.1.43 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           04-a1-51-30-01-07     dynamic
  192.168.1.2           00-40-9d-67-5e-3c     dynamic
  192.168.1.19          b0-fc-36-76-e9-ad     dynamic
  192.168.1.76          00-00-00-04-fd-7f     dynamic
  192.168.1.250         9c-3d-cf-e1-d8-0c     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.1.60            01-00-5e-00-01-3c     static
  224.0.6.151           01-00-5e-00-06-97     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: The first reply is from your own IP address. That means your own device (not some other device like a router) was the one letting you know the address was unreachable. This problem is likely to come down to a problem with your ARP table or your route table. It would be helpful to have snapshots of both tables both immediately after wakeup when the problem will happen, and immediately after the problem has cleared up.

Comment: This sounds like a feature, on the network switch, might be to blame for the behavior. What are the specifications of the network switch? If you set the LAN adapter to a static DHCP assignment does the behavior change?

Comment: I just tried disconnecting the cable, and I get the same "host unreachable" reply from `43` IP. I wonder if OS is getting confused which route to take, since both adapters have the same IP range/mask?

Comment: It seems the problem was that during W10 I had issues where I didn't have internet, because OS was trying use wired network by default, so I've changed `Automatic metric` in IP4 configuration to manual number in each adapter. Once I set it back to auto, it fixed the issue.

Comment: after sleep it takes a while before networking is established.

Comment: @moab, not in this case though. It didn't matter how long I'd wait before trying to connect to the device after login. Now with the fix above, it works instantly.

Comment: @vanowm: You should put up and answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was that during W10 time I had issues where I didn't have internet, because OS was trying use wired network by default, so I've changed `Automatic metric` in IP4 configuration of each adapter to manual number.

After I set it back to `auto`, it fixed the issue.
[image]